# Hebrew being Lashon HaKodesh, is the inclusion and exclusion of certain phonemes and sounds in the language significant?

Tags: hebrew, pronunciation, language, speech-talking, kedusha-holiness

For instance, the English sounds of "J", "W","Th", and "Ch" are for the most part unused in Hebrew. Although as an exception, I've seen a Yemenite Chazan use some of these sounds while reading the Torah.

Does the particular makeup of the language mean that only the included sounds are capable of being holy? Is there some other significance to it?

Comment: By "Ch", do you mean the [voiceless palato-alveolar affricate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_palato-alveolar_affricate) (e.g. as in the name Charlie)? Because, if I understand your transliteration correctly, there are Yemenites who pronounce the other sounds in "גּ" ([/dʒ/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_palato-alveolar_affricate)), "ו" ([/w/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labio-velar_approximant)), and "ת" ([/θ/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_dental_fricative)) or "ד" ([/ð/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental_fricative)), respectively (as you mentioned).

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Hebrew_phonology#Regional_and_historical_variation (but ignore the letters with apostrophes; they are [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geresh#Diacritic) relevant only to modern Israeli Hebrew).

Comment: Yes, that's the sound I'm talking about, but that was just an example. Not every possible human sound is included in the Hebrew language, which is where this question comes from. Hebrew is made up of particular sounds (with regional  / cultural differences). Is there a reason why only these sounds are included in Lashon Hakodesh, the language with which the world was created? Is there something else significant about these particular sounds? What does this say about other languages?

Comment: Some of those are not the best examples, I'm afraid, since many Europeans nationals often mispronounce in English "v" as "w" (and vice versa) and "th" as "s" or "t" As Rav Yaakov Emden, z"l, complained in his Siddur "לא כמו שאנו האשכנזים עושים בקריאת תי״ו רפויה כסמ״ך לבשתינו" as cited in this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53498/may-one-mix-and-match-to-create-their-own-hebrew-pronunciation )

Comment: "ch" is technically also constructable as "טש" - "tsh".

Comment: Related (ch): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45738/the-lack-of-ch-sound-in-hebrew

Comment: @Scimonster, not a duplicate?

Comment: @msh210 No, because this also wants to know about several other sounds.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting R' Avraham DeBalmash: "lashon hakodesh contains all possible movements of the mouth, but there is controversy as to what letter signifies which sound", on which he elaborates between differrent methods.

The yemenites have (some of them at least) kept the original pronounciation intact,
where today many if not most Jews have lost some of the more obscure and uncommon sounds in their native country to an extent.

Comment: Googling "Avraham DeBalmash" gets me no results at all, for what it's worth.

Comment: This is definitely false. Even if we gave every letter a dagesh kal form, a dagesh chazak form, and a shin/sin dot form, that would only be 88 sounds. There are more than 88 different sounds in the International Phonetic Alphabet, even just in the pulmonic consonant section!

Comment: @msh210 see https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D_%D7%93%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A9

Comment: @DoubleAA there could be more than one sound per letter. For example, you could have an undotted ת be [t] at the start of a word, [θ] at the start of a syllable in the middle of a word, [s] at the end of a closed syllable after a _kamatz katan_, and [ʈ] at the end of a closed syllable otherwise, except in one particular word where it's [ɽ] for some reason.

Comment: The reason there are many more sounds in the IPhA is because diphtongs are used and Lashon hakodesh expressly considers diphtongs of any sort as two vowels  and not a single movement of the mouth.

Comment: @Samuel diphthongs are vowels. There are well over 88 consonants in IPA and anyway 88 is a joke since clearly most hebrew letters don't have a shin/sin dot or dagesh kal. Do I really need to start listing sounds that don't appear in Hebrew? Which letter indicates African click sounds? Which letter indicates a sneeze?

Comment: I apologise, I meant any consonant as well in that ch in charlie which is actually tsh, is considered as two seperate movements and this applies to vowels as well. And Xhosa doesn't count as Hebrew expressly uses the bumaph, datlant etc. sources. The letters in Hebrew moreover, indicate speech, not a bad cold.

Comment: I can't believe we're actually doing this... Which letter means american r? Which letter mean french j? Which letter is the bilabial trill as found in Kwomtari? How does hebrew distinguish aspirated and unaspirated p as in classical greek? English ch represents an affricate and was not included in the pulmonic consonants mentioned above. A sneeze is certainly included in "all possible movements of the mouth"

Comment: @msh210 lol :-)

Comment: American r = untrilled r is a light form of Reish. j = is Yud d'gusha, but is under controversy, some say it is Gimel. Aspirated p is Pei un -> Fei. Really, if you want to learn Hebrew, there are millions of courses out there.

Comment: Expressly, what languages do you know? if you know latin R' Eliyahu Bachur wrote a book in Hebrew and latin that teaches hebrew, and you can see the equivalents in Latin. I'm off!

Comment: Those answers are factually incorrect. American r is not a form of reish, it's an approximant. French j is not yud/gimel, that's american j. And pei/fei is plosive vs fricative, not aspirated vs unaspirated.